# Material Preview is not displaying correctly!

Tags: rendering, mesh, texturing

I downloaded a Material via Bridge to Blender. Assigned it to a Mesh.
But unfortunately, it is not displaying correctly. It is kinda grayed out?!

[image]

Can someone help out?

Best regards
Til

Comment: Add a stronger light in the scene

Comment: Hello :). Rendered view is using your flat grey world environment by default. All colors look a bit dull without good lighting or HDRI.